Unable to move cluster resource using PCS
I am using the corosync, pacemaker and PCS tool to manage the cluster service for SMTP outgoing servers.
I am finding a weird issue, when I try to move the cluster using resource group, it throws an error as below. not able to identify what I am missing.
[~]# pcs resource move prmcnzzeml02
Error: Unable to move resource 'ausprmcnzzeml02' using a location constraint. Current location of the resource may be affected by some other constraint.

This is the pcs status:
[root@prnnxeml02 ~]# pcs status
Cluster name: PRNZZEML02
Cluster Summary:
  * Stack: corosync (Pacemaker is running)
  * Current DC: prnnxeml02.host.com (version 2.1.7-5.0.1.el9_4-0f7f88312) - partition with quorum
  * Last updated: Mon Jun 24 18:05:09 2024 on prnnxeml02.host.com
  * Last change:  Mon Jun 24 15:04:19 2024 by root via root on prnnxeml02.host.com
  * 2 nodes configured
  * 3 resource instances configured

Node List:
  * Online: [ prnnxeml02.host.com prnnyeml02.host.com ]

Full List of Resources:
  * Resource Group: prnzzeml02:
    * Address   (ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2):         Started prnnxeml02.host.com
    * Sendmail  (systemd:sendmail):      Started prnnxeml02.host.com
    * OpenDkim  (systemd:opendkim):      Started prnnxeml02.host.com

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled

[root@prmcnnxeml02 ~]# pcs constraint config --full
Colocation Constraints:
  resource 'Sendmail' with resource 'Address' (id: colocation-Sendmail-Address-INFINITY)
    score=INFINITY
  resource 'OpenDkim' with resource 'Sendmail' (id: colocation-OpenDkim-Sendmail-INFINITY)
    score=INFINITY
Order Constraints:
  start resource 'Address' then start resource 'Sendmail' (id: order-Address-Sendmail-Mandatory)
    kind=Mandatory
  start resource 'Sendmail' then start resource 'OpenDkim' (id: order-Sendmail-OpenDkim-Mandatory)
    kind=Mandatory

Both server have similar versions installed.

prnnxeml02 

[root@prnnxeml02 ~]# yum list installed | grep pacemaker
pacemaker.x86_64                      2.1.7-5.0.1.el9_4                   @oraclelinux9-x86_64-addons
pacemaker-cli.x86_64                  2.1.7-5.0.1.el9_4                   @oraclelinux9-x86_64-addons
pacemaker-cluster-libs.x86_64         2.1.7-5.0.1.el9_4                   @oraclelinux9-x86_64-addons
pacemaker-libs.x86_64                 2.1.7-5.0.1.el9_4                   @oraclelinux9-x86_64-addons
pacemaker-schemas.noarch              2.1.7-5.0.1.el9_4                   @oraclelinux9-x86_64-addons
[root@prnnxeml02 ~]#
[root@prnnxeml02 ~]#
[root@prnnxeml02 ~]# yum list installed | grep corosync
corosync.x86_64                       3.1.8-1.el9                         @oraclelinux9-x86_64-addons
corosynclib.x86_64                    3.1.8-1.el9                         @oraclelinux9-x86_64-appstream
[root@prnnxeml02 ~]#
[root@prnnxeml02 ~]#
[root@prnnxeml02 ~]# yum list installed | grep pcs
pcs.x86_64                            0.11.7-2.el9_4                      @oraclelinux9-x86_64-addons

prnnyeml02 

[root@prnnyeml02 ~]# yum list installed | grep pacemaker
pacemaker.x86_64                      2.1.7-5.0.1.el9_4                   @oraclelinux9-x86_64-addons
pacemaker-cli.x86_64                  2.1.7-5.0.1.el9_4                   @oraclelinux9-x86_64-addons
pacemaker-cluster-libs.x86_64         2.1.7-5.0.1.el9_4                   @oraclelinux9-x86_64-addons
pacemaker-libs.x86_64                 2.1.7-5.0.1.el9_4                   @oraclelinux9-x86_64-addons
pacemaker-schemas.noarch              2.1.7-5.0.1.el9_4                   @oraclelinux9-x86_64-addons
[root@prnnyeml02 ~]#
[root@prnnyeml02 ~]#
[root@prnnyeml02 ~]#  yum list installed | grep corosync
corosync.x86_64                       3.1.8-1.el9                         @oraclelinux9-x86_64-addons
corosynclib.x86_64                    3.1.8-1.el9                         @oraclelinux9-x86_64-appstream
[root@prnnyeml02 ~]#
[root@prnnyeml02 ~]#
[root@prnnyeml02 ~]# yum list installed | grep pcs
pcs.x86_64                            0.11.7-2.el9_4                      @oraclelinux9-x86_64-addons

Let me know if you need any more details from pacemaker, corosync logs, I can paste it.
